# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'code'

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I am writing a MongoDB Query like this:
    Message.objects.filter( Q(author_id=user.id) | Q(for_user_id=user.id) | Q( shared_with_id=user.id)).order_by( "-timestamp")[:10]

The versions are

MongoDB = 1.8.2
Pymonogo :1.11

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/mnt/install/wwm/thirdparty/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in    get_response
response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/mnt/install/wwm/thirdparty/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapped_view
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

 File "/mnt/install/wwm/main/views.py", line 1232, in user_messages
 mesg_list = list(Message.objects( Q(author_id=user.id) | Q(for_user_id=user.id) | Q( shared_with_id=user.id)).order_by( "-timestamp")[:10])

 File "/mnt/install/wwm/thirdparty/mongoengine/queryset.py", line 223, in call
 self._where_clause = q_obj.as_js(self._document)

  File "/mnt/install/wwm/thirdparty/mongoengine/queryset.py", line 89, in as_js
  return pymongo.code.Code(' '.join(js), js_scope)

 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'code'
```

The same line of code is working fine with
pymongo : 2.0.1
mongodb : 2.1.0

Can you tell where exactly is error or any workoaround since i dont want to update the pymongo.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned on github:

> Pymongo 1.11 is no longer supported. I would advise to updating
>   pymongo if possible. If not possible, you need to look at the imports
>   as Code and others have been moved to the bson module.

What version of MongoEngine are you using?

Comment: how to check the mongoengine version. I found this VERSION = (0, 3, 0) in __init__.py

Comment: ok thats it - you are running an old version of mongoengine, currently its 0.6.9  It has changed significantly, do you have an existing codebase / reason for not wanting to upgrade pymongo / mongoengine?

Comment: As far as I can tell it should work in pymongo 1.11 but not in the latest as pymongo.code was depreciated in 1.9 and removed in 2.2

Comment: Thanks Ross,
I need to do two things. One Upgrade the pymongo to 2.2 ie the latest version and the mongoengine files. Also FYI i am using MongoDB 1.8, thus rest is fine ? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I would recommend upgrading to mongodb 2.0 - theres better concurrency, so its faster and better indexing.  But I realise that might not be possible.